# How can I compare two fields of a subdocument that exists within an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I match a document whose property `A` - an array of embedded documents - includes one such as `subDocument.propertyX < subDocument.propertyY`? Tried:

```js
'A': {
    $elemMatch: {
        propertyX: {
            $lt: '$propertyY',
        },
    },
},
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tdwpjYUKSL_)

Comment: do you have a sample input and output

Comment: @cmgchess https://mongoplayground.net/p/tdwpjYUKSL_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. you could do something like below. [`$filter`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the `A` subdoc array that satisfy the condition and get the [`$size`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of that array. If the size of that array is greater than (`$gt`) 0 it means there is at least 1 that satisfies the condition `subDocument.propertyX < subDocument.propertyY`. Also [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$A",
            as: "subDocument",
            cond: { $lt: [ "$$subDocument.propertyX", "$$subDocument.propertyY" ] }
          }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VPGCgD0Z_Sw)

**2**. another way of doing using [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$anyElementTrue`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) in an aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      hasMatch: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$A",
            as: "subDocument",
            in: { $lt: [ "$$subDocument.propertyX", "$$subDocument.propertyY" ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { hasMatch: true } },
  { $project: { hasMatch: 0 } }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CSBGe9Owj4Z)